# React Updating Arrays in State

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-maps and trying to draw multiple polylines. I have grouped points in this structure in state:

```
var groups = [{
    Key: 'YELLOW',
    Points: [],
}]
```

Now I want to push lat/lng objects in Points array but it gives object not extensible error. I tried to expand attibutes using [... this.state.groups] but I can't push Points in it.

I have a separate array which contains a similar structure which has all the points data. The concept here is that I need to push that data in to this group data structure with a delay for each point so the polylines/route draws slowly.

Comment: Try `groups[0].Points.concat(new_value)`

Comment: @ravibagul91 How about removing element? I tried splice, didn't work.

Comment: Check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Also this - https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I used splice and concat functions in this way:

For adding

```
this.setState((state) => {

    var newArray = [...state.cordinates, {
        latitude: point.latitude,
        longitude: point.longitude,
    }];

    return {
        cordinates: newArray,
    };

});
```

For removal:

```
this.setState((state) => {

    var newArray = [...this.state.cordinates];

    newArray.splice(-1, 1);

    return {
        cordinates: newArray,
    };

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the following structure

```
const groups = [{Key: 'YELLOW',Points: [],},{Key: 'BLUE',Points: [],}]
```

And you want to push a pair of `lat/lng` into each `Points`, this could be achieved by doing

```
const pushPoint = point =>{
    const updatedGroups = group.map(group =>({
        ...group,
        Points : group.Points.concat(point)
    }))

    return updatedGroups
}

this.setState({groups : this.pushPoint(this.state.groups)})
```

You need to `spread` the original group, and overwrite the `Points` property by returning a new array which is the result of the concatenation of the previous `Points` and the new `point`

Comment: How about removing element? I tried splice, didn't work.

Comment: You should use filter. `array.filter(x => x.id !== idToRemove)`

Answer (score 1):

let his nwe arry

```
 const totsl= [{key: 'YELLOW',Points: [],},{Key: 'BLUE',Points: [30,40],}],
```

to use this .state.groups you should

```
state={groups = [{
    Key: 'YELLOW',
    Points: [],
}};

totsl.Points.map(item=>
this.setState({this.state.groups.Points:item})
to add in the state Points it should b use this syntax this.state({groups :{points:value"}}
```

,

tell me if it works or still has problem

Comment: How about removing element? I tried splice, didn't work.

Comment: use filter. example totsl.Points.filter(item=>item.id 1 !== id)